# React navigation 5 authentication flow not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a simple authentication flow in my react native app in which once a user logs in he should not be able to go back to the log in screen. But unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I created two different navigator for my signed state but once I am logged in and am on my home page, when I go back I still can go to the log in screen which I don't want. Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

AppNavigator.js

```
const AppNavigator=()=>{
  const [isSignedIn, setisSignedIn] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted=true;
    if(mounted){
        initializeApp();
    }
    return () => {
        mounted=false;
    }
  }, [])
  function initializeApp(){
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
        if(user){
          setisSignedIn(true);
          
        }else{
          setisSignedIn(false);
        }
        setLoading(false);
}
if(loading){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>  
      <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
if(!isSignedIn){
  return(
    <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>  
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginForm" component={LoginForm}></Stack.Screen>
      <Stack.Screen name="OTPScreen" component={OTPScreen}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}else{
    return(
      <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
      }}>  
      <Stack.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage}></Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>

  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fragment to wrap the navigation:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

return (
  <>
    {loading ? <SplashScreen /> : null}
    {isSignedIn ? (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator
         screenOptions={{
           headerShown: false,
         }}
       >
         <Stack.Screen name="HomePage" component={HomePage}></Stack.Screen>
       </Stack.Navigator>
     <NavigationContainer/>
    ) : (
     <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator
         screenOptions={{
           headerShown: false,
         }}
       >
         <Stack.Screen name="LoginForm" component={LoginForm}></Stack.Screen>
         <Stack.Screen name="OTPScreen" component={OTPScreen}></Stack.Screen>
       </Stack.Navigator>
     <NavigationContainer/>
    )}
  </>
);
```

Comment: I tried doing it this way but still when I go back from home screen it goes to my OTPScreen. This is a major hurdle for iOS where we swipe right to go back. When I swipe right on my HomeScreen it just goes to the OTP screen unfortunately.

Comment: Would you please try to wrap the Stack.Navigator with NavigationContainer? @Knevagi

Comment: Doing this is giving me an exception of nested navigation containers.

Comment: Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitely. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.

Comment: Did you notice that I missplaced the slash for NavigationContainer? on the closing tag. have you fixed it?@Knevagi